# Should questions about recipes involving coffee be considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm not talking about recipes for specific coffees, but more like recipes for other food and drinks that include coffee, perhaps even as the primary flavour.

For example, coffee desserts, coffee milkshakes, etc.

Should these be considered on topic here because they involve coffee to such an extent that the choice of bean / roast etc, is likely to affect overall flavour, or should they be designated as off-topic because they are not, in and of themselves, coffees.

To add to that, if we are to ban questions about coffee milkshakes, where do we draw the line between some of the milkier, flavoured iced coffees and milkshakes?

Answer (score 8):

It's pretty simple. If they're asking about brewing components, or brewing technique - they're on topic. If it's more about cooking components, or cooking technique, then it's probably one for [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com).

There is going to be overlap, and you should be *insanely* jealous when it comes to your site - you want any good question that fits within the topic to stay *here*. Coffee is a common ingredient in many popular deserts, and fits well here, as long as the 'gist' requires knowledge of not just cooking, but also coffee in order to answer.

I wouldn't do anything now, there's less than 200 questions so far, and the site isn't even public yet. When you get to ~500 questions and there's a bigger sampling of these, then it's *much* easier to identify factors that make something a solid fit here rather than somewhere else.

Comment: This came up [here](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/q/1146/230) in a sort of awkward way - an unexplained migration. Maybe it's worth revisiting this slightly? (On the other hand, the site is not too close to 500 questions.)

Comment: I should also say: we have not been migrating questions from cooking, but we may revisit that. Coffee has always been in scope on cooking and it was unclear how well this site would fare, so we were very wary of telling users they were in the wrong place, and possibly sending them to a beta site that wouldn't have enough activity. But [the recent updates on beta sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/133299) may remove some of that conern.