# Questions about Iced Coffee?

Tags: discussion

This has partially been covered [here](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/should-questions-about-recipes-involving-coffee-be-considered-off-topic), but was more broad than *specifically **iced coffee***

Are questions about the *beverage* iced coffee here appropriate? Such as differences in bean types, preparation etc?

Comment: So, what's your question? [Ask away!](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ;-)

Comment: @hoc_age tongue-tied! any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iced Coffee is Coffee, so absolutely, yes!